# Django Postgres JSONB and using a JSONB index

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

So we have a value stored in a JSONB column which I need to query on. I created an index for it like so

```
create index user_notification_policy_id on user_notification using btree (((extra->'policy_id')::int8));
```

The explain plan is using the index if the query is formatted as so

```
("user_notification"."extra" -> 'policy_id')::text = '12345678');
```

How can I get Django to create a where clause like that? I've been trying to use `extra` but without luck

```
return self.extra(
            where='("extra"->"policy_id")::int8 = %s',
            params=[policy_id]
        )
```

results in

```
E       ValueError: unsupported format character ')' (0x29) at index 1061
```

Django 2.2.16

Answer (score 0):

I had the extra formatted wrong. It should be an array

```
return self.extra(
            where=['("extra"->\'policy_id\')::int8 = %s'],
            params=[policy_id]
        )
```